# Manually install a python distribute package occuring IOError: CRC check failed

Tags: python, ubuntu, crc

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I wanted to enable ubuntu one at first. So I ran `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt`. Then it said `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`. The solutions I found on Internet said it could be fixed by reinstalling the python distribute package. So I used `curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.yp` and then `python distribute_setup.py`But an annoying message appeared, saying that `IOError: CRC check failed 0x77057d99 != 0xec0a9eeL`I was almost driven crazy. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloaded file is most likely corrupted, try re-downloading it again. (Also note the `distribute_setup.yp` extension typo).