# IOError: CRC check failed 0xffca51ff != 0x3679ba0L

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip, crc, ioerror

I'm trying to run a [script](https://github.com/rkadlec/ubuntu-ranking-dataset-creator) that downloads and generates datasets from the Ubuntu Dialogue Corpus v2.0, but it fails with the following error:

```
Unpacking dialogs ...
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "create_ubuntu_dataset.py", line 404, in <module> prepare_data_maybe_download(args.data_root)
   File "create_ubuntu_dataset.py", line 267, in prepare_data_maybe_download tar.extractall(path=directory)
   File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2073, in extractall for tarinfo in members:
  File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2508, in next
    tarinfo = self.tarfile.next()
  File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2356, in next
    tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)
  File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1251, in fromtarfile
    buf = tarfile.fileobj.read(BLOCKSIZE)
  File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 268, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 315, in _read
    self._read_eof()
  File "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 354, in _read_eof
    hex(self.crc)))
IOError: CRC check failed 0xffca51ff != 0x3679ba0L
0
```

I have all my paths set correctly so I'm almost certain that it has nothing to do with that. I didn't see any explicit instruction to use Python3 so I sticked with 2.7. Also, I'm running the script with all three -t -s -l parameters.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Manually install a python distribute package occuring IOError: CRC check failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859553/manually-install-a-python-distribute-package-occuring-ioerror-crc-check-failed)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues too. Then I deleted the folder where I started the docker container. Then it works again!
It was due to my half downloaded retrain.py